# C# save excel with macro enabled but MsgBox disabled

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have empty excel file with only one event implemented:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim dWorkSheet
    Set dWorkSheet = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    For i = 1 To 15
        For j = 1 To 15
            If Not IsEmpty(dWorkSheet.Cells(i, j)) Then
                dWorkSheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 180, 255)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    MsgBox ("saved")
End Sub
```

And My c# program:

```
static void Main()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excel.ScreenUpdating = false;
    excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excel.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
    Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("excel.xlsm");
    Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
    Range r = excelSheet.UsedRange;
    for (int row = 1; row <= 15; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 15; col++)
        {
            excelSheet.Cells[row, col] = row * col;
        }
    }
    wb.Save();
    wb.Close(false);

    excel.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelSheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
}
```

I don't want the MsgBox to be displayed.
But I want the macro to be run.
How can I get that result?
I have tried changing
`excel.AutomationSecurity` and  `excel.DisplayAlerts`
but I always had only two results.
BeforeSave do the work but MsgBox displayed or BeforeSave Not worked and MsgBox not displayed.

Comment: You would either need to change the macro by your C# code or you would need to patch the MsgBox method so that it returns immediately. Both is likely not so simple. Another ugly solution could be to send a Space keypress to that window.

Comment: Are you really talking about the VBA MsgBox? Would you like to save the workbook (in C#), but MsgBox ("saved") from Workbook_BeforeSave event to not run? Does your question reflect the above understanding? If the answer is yes, you cannot do that in the way you tries, I am afraid. But you can build your own event in C#: Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler Custom_BeforeBookClose; And you can write its code without the MsgBox. There are (also here) examples on the net to do that. May I know why such a need? Theoretically you can modify the existing code event, too (in C# code)...

Comment: You just need a flag that will show the msgbox or not. Just set it to false when opened in C#. A custom document property perhaps?